# Part of url lost when dragging text between inputs

Tags: html, google-chrome

See the code example below. When you select the text in the first input and drag it to the second input, what you are left with in the second input is just the text 'questions'.

Can anyone explain why this happens and if there's a way to keep all the text when dragging?

Thanks!

```html
<input type="text" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to drag some text from a text input to an empty text input. It will fail, and will raise an assert in debug builds:
ASSERT(oldLength >= selectionLength);

I think this is because WebCore is calculating oldLength from the wrong element; it looks like it's calculating the length of the text field being dragged to rather than the text field being dragged from.

Comment: Super annoying bug.